# XMLHttpRequest to site without URL parameters

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

im not sure if this is possibile but im trying get a citys name from lat long coords. Ive found a site that does it pretty well and would like to do a XMLHttpRequest to that site.

Ive tried with google by doing this:

```
var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
```

and it returns all the info, but i wanted to use this site: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html

which doesnt take the lat and long in the Url but instead inputs on the web page. Is this possible? thanks

Comment: No. You should replicate the same code that other site uses in your own site

Comment: on that site, it uses a script tag to get some sort of api, but i wanted to do it server side. Thats why i wanted to do it though xmlrequest instead @charlietfl

Comment: First, what do your want to achieve?

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of server side coding are you going to use as well

Comment: @RobertAnthonyS.Tribiana just want to return the city from a users lat, long coords with node. I tried using their librarys and 40% of the time returns an error. At the moment im just using the same code as the site i linked and it sends the city to the server. Its not ideal as the client could send anything but i dont really have any other option

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what do you want to achieve is **Reverse Geocoding**

```
Here is the documentation from Google Maps:
```

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding.

```
Sample Call to Google's geocode Web Service:
```

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

I created Codepen too for you to play with. That is almost the same as the site you are referring
https://codepen.io/ratribiana/pen/ELNJaK